# SVG styles behaving unexpectedly, not respecting parent containers' height?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to create a TextField component that takes an optional left adornment component, which renders a container with an SVG icon within it, where the SVG icon is centered within the parent.

The problem here is that the parent of the SVG element is, for some reason, setting an (arbitrary?) height for itself. Not sure why this is happening, maybe it's got something to do with the SVG props themselves.

If I set the `Container` height to `3rem`, for example, then the adornments' parent containers height does change, but the SVG itself keeps extending outside of the bounds.

[image: frosty-euler-913bhv]

Here's how it looks like now:

[image: img2]

And here is how I'd like it to look like:

[image: img]

Here's the code:

```
// TextField
import * as React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const Container = styled.div`
  --input-color: #99a3ba;
  --input-border: #cdd9ed;
  --input-border-error: #a30000;
  --input-background: #fff;
  --input-placeholder: #cbd1dc;

  --input-border-focus: #275efe;

  --group-color: var(--input-color);
  --group-border: var(--input-border);
  --group-background: #eef4ff;

  --group-color-focus: #fff;
  --group-border-focus: var(--input-border-focus);
  --group-background-focus: #678efe;

  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  & > .adornment_container,
  .form-field {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    &:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    &:first-child {
      border-radius: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
    }
    &:not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: 1px;
    }
  }
  .form-field {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 1%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  & > .adornment_container {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--group-color);
    background: var(--group-background);
    border: 1px solid var(--group-border);
    transition: background 0.3s ease, border 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
  }
  &:focus-within {
    & > .adornment_container {
      color: var(--group-color-focus);
      background: var(--group-background-focus);
      border-color: var(--group-border-focus);

      path {
        fill: #ffffff;
      }
    }
  }
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: inherit;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: var(--input-color);
  border: 1px solid var(--input-border);
  background: var(--input-background);
  transition: border 0.3s ease;
  &::placeholder {
    color: var(--input-placeholder);
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: var(--input-border-focus);
  }
`;

const AdornmentContent = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
`;

type TextFieldProps = {
  adornmentContent?: React.ReactNode;
  value: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
} & Omit<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, "name">;
const TextField = React.memo(
  ({
    className,
    adornmentContent = null,
    disabled,
    ...props
  }: TextFieldProps) => {
    const adornment = adornmentContent ? (
      <AdornmentContent className="adornment_container">
        {adornmentContent}
      </AdornmentContent>
    ) : null;

    return (
      <Container>
        {adornment}
        <Input className={clsx("form-field", className)} {...props} />
      </Container>
    );
  }
);

export default TextField;
```

```
// EmailIcon
import * as React from "react";

const EmailIcon = React.memo(() => {
  return (
    <svg
      aria-hidden="true"
      viewBox="0 0 100% 100%"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <path
        d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10h5v-2h-5c-4.34 0-8-3.66-8-8s3.66-8 8-8 8 3.66 8 8v1.43c0 .79-.71 1.57-1.5 1.57s-1.5-.78-1.5-1.57V12c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5s-5 2.24-5 5 2.24 5 5 5c1.38 0 2.64-.56 3.54-1.47.65.89 1.77 1.47 2.96 1.47 1.97 0 3.5-1.6 3.5-3.57V12c0-5.52-4.48-10-10-10zm0 13c-1.66 0-3-1.34-3-3s1.34-3 3-3 3 1.34 3 3-1.34 3-3 3z"
        fill={"#232323"}
      />
    </svg>
  );
});

export default EmailIcon;
```

What am I doing wrong here? Here is how I would like it to look like:

[image: img]

Comment: viewBox does not take percentages. You need 4 numbers only.

Comment: svg height 100%, viewbox 0 0 100% 100% not acceptable (numbers only), css-bx1x7i height 100%... All 100% (1 wrong) of nothing. Your icon itself is 20px x 20px, if you give real value to viewbox, try 0 0 40px 40px (or 30 but not 20), and it's height to 20px, it's ok

Comment: `viewBox="0 0 24 24"`` is more suitable.  Due to the invalid viewBox values the browser takes the fallback height of 150px. You should also apply either a height or width when using relative units (e.g height:1em) or only absolute units like `height: 1rem; width:1rem`